# How do I use rspec mock methods from inside a custom DSL

Tags: ruby, dsl

I'm writing a testing library that works on top of rspec. I have a custom dsl that looks like this:

```
rast Worker do
  prepare do |day_type, dow|
    allow(subject).to receive(:holiday?) { day_type == 'Holiday' }
    allow(subject).to receive(:dow) { dow }
  end

  execute do
    result subject.goto_work?
  end
end
```

The two `allow` statements do not work because they are inside my custom DSL `rast` with the method `prepare`. How can I make it work?

Inside the `execute` method I invoke this `prepare` block like this:

```
  def execute
    prepare_block = @prepare_block
    RSpec.describe "test" do
        prepare_block&.call(*params)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the whole picture, but at a guess and off the top of my mind, you may fare better with something like

```
RSpec.describe "test" do
  instance_eval(prepare_block, *params) if prepare_block
end
```

[`instance_eval`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_eval) will evaluate the block in the context of the receiver (so whatever `self` is inside the `describe` block).

If you just do `prepare_block.call`, it won't have access to any methods defined in the context where it happened to be called from, as you found out.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your tip and encouragement, `instance_eval` gave me an idea, and you gave me motivation. What I did is implement a `method_missing` then I stored the calls into a stack which I then process later inside the RSpec `describe`. Not pretty but gets the job done.  It's not yet complete but I'm closer to my goal now.